# JavaScript form with decimal numbers

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form which for now is only accepting integers, how can I have a form which accept decimals?

Also how can I activate a keyboard in HTML that has a keypad and a decimal point?

My JavaScript code for now is this:

```
var peso = parseInt(form.elements["x"].valueAsNumber);
var eta = parseInt(form.elements["y"].valueAsNumber);
var creatinina = parseInt(form.elements["c"].valueAsNumber);
```

and for the variables in HTML form, this:

```
<p align="center" style="font-size:20px">Peso (kg)</p>
<input name="x" type="number" value="70" style="width:100%;height:40px;font-size:15px;" pattern="\d*"/>
```

Comment: do you expect parseInt() to parse decimals ?

Comment: Maybe the pattern can be `[\d\.]*` (Though yes, this would allow multiple decimal points)

Comment: And yes, you'd have to use `parseFloat`

Comment: If you're only targeting newer browsers, you can use <input type="number"/> and not need JS.

Comment: The pattern Mike suggested will show the complete keyboard with also ?,! and so on and not only che numbers with the decimal point

Answer (score 0):

The way to handle it is to use an `<input type="text">` and add a proper javascript-match.

```
<input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" maxlength="6" autocomplete="off"/></span>
```

After any change in this field happened, you could check against a regular expression like that one:

```
var ok = /^\d*\.?\d*$/.test(input);
```

If you think the input is correct, everything is fine. If not, you can print a message that this box should accept a decimal.

Answer (score 0):

try this one to make you textbox able to accept only Numbers and decimals.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<SCRIPT language=Javascript>
   <!--
   function isNumberKey(evt)
   {
      var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
      if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 
        && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
         return false;

      return true;
   }
   //-->
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
   <INPUT name="x" style="width:100%;height:40px;font-size:15px;" id="txtChar" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" 
       type="text">
</BODY>
</HTML>
```